# Magento 2 Attributes Price Does't Update

Tags: magento, attributes, magento2, price

A friend of mine who running e-commerce website using Magento 2 platform. She set price attribute on her products and now she wants to change the price. She is able to find the attribute input field and changed the price and then saved and cashed out, but it doesn't update frontend, and there is no any error show either.

I'm pretty new to Magento 2 and wondering any body has any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You must flush storage cache then run this command (from the root of magento's directory) line to get the change applied :

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Let me know if you still face the problem then.

Comment: I use React and Redux for my application but I'm  pretty new to Magento 2 platform. Are you saying I should go to web hosting Control Panel and excuse the '$php bin/magento indexer:reindex' ?     If I excuse this line from terminal and then I have to deploy whole codes  again? Help?

Comment: You can access server by SSH program and run the command there (like putty). You don't need to deploy code again, Just run the "reindex"  then flush cache as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot ssh to server, you can go to admin System->Tools->Index Management to Re